# One computer has "limited connectivity", and wrong IP, from one wall socket

Tags: networking, ethernet, protocol, wired

The problem is only at one point of the wired network. If the computer is connected to a different point it works.

Running ipconfig  shows it has a different IP address and no DNS data at this socket.

But if the computer is moved to a different socket the everything goes back to normal.

Running flushdns & release has not worked.

Running ipconfig at the bad socket shows, "Media disconnected", "connection-specific DNS"

Answer (score 2):

I would hazard a guess that you have identified the problem yourself by using the phrase "bad socket".

What happens if you plug a different computer into the socket?

Comment: It runs fine from some other sockets but not all. The way the sockets are distributed it is unlikely it is a wiring problem. It's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Is the IP address 169.XX.XX.XX when plugged in on the bad wall jack? If your using Windows, this would be the default IP address the OS gives when it can't receive an IP address from the wired source.  If your computer seems to work from another jack, it's most likely one of a few things:

1. Check the wall jack, are the wires inside bent or crossed?

2. If not, is the ethernet cord from the jack to server/router bad or stripped somewhere

3. Is the port disabled/broken at the server/router?

If this is your network, check and test those out, if its an office/school network, tell the network administrator so they can further test and fix it

Comment: Yes, the I.P. is 169.xx, running Vista.

1 & 2.The wires aren't bent or crossed and it doesn't work with spare cables either. Testing it in some other unused sockets there is the same problem, but in others it is fine.

3. The router is at least partially functional because all the other computers have a connection.

Testing other jacks in the area and there is the same problem with some (there has never been a problem with these others before) but not the other. The way the jacks are positioned it seems unlikely that it is the wiring.